# Rewrite search URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For some reason I can't seem to get my head around this. I've formatted all of my pages as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ view-page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

All works great. However, I've got a search form (using get) that I'd like the URL to result in:

> website.com/search/searchterm

But really struggling. So far, I've got it so that it goes to my homepage:

> website.com/?search=searchterm

Which I actually need to point to my search.php page.

I'm sure this is quite basic but it's been bamboozling me for way too long now!

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /search\.php\?search=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /search/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ /search.php?search=$1 [L]
```